# Is it possible to save for web and devices with dash in illustrator?

Tags: web, format, save, filenames, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to save with "save for web and devices" features with dash in illustrator,

like this
"save for web and devices", 
not like 
"save-for-web-and-devices",

if it's possible can someone explain to me ?, 
if it's not can you please give me an explanation why adobe create a name formatting like this, 
thank you !.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter if its "save for web and devices" or "save-for-web-and-devices". What really matters is the functionality.
And you can really choose various options inside it.